# PHP Fatal error Zend Uncaught Exception

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend-framework

I'm using Zend framework 1.11 to develop a site hosted on a centos server.  Apache is running and documentroot is set to "var/www/html/public".  When I copy my index.php file from my Zend Framework project to this directory and browse to http://www.localhost nothing appears, the same is true when browsing to localhost/html/public/index.php.

I noted that the Zend Framework folder needed to be copied to /usr/share/php/Zend which did not exist until I created it tonight.  After copying  the Zend folder there, my browser still gives a blank page.  I used php -f /var/www/html/public/index.php and received the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message    
'parse_ini_file(/var/www/html/application/configs/application.ini): failed to open
stream: No such file or directory' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Config/Ini.php:182
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Config/Ini.php(202): Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/var
/www/html/a...')
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Config/Ini.php(126): Zend_Config_Ini->_loadIniFile('/var
/www/html/a...')
#2 /usr/share/php/Zend/Application.php(386): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/var
/www/html/a...', 'production')
#3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Application.php(85): Zend_Application->_loadConfig('/var
/www/html/a...')
#4 /var/www/html/public/index.php(24): Zend_Application->__construct('production',
'/var/www/html/a...')
#5 {main}
thrown in /usr/share/php/Zend/Config/Ini.php on line 182
```

I'm quickly coming up on a Thursday deadline and desperately need to understand what needs to be done to remedy this situation.  Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to this question, taken from the error message, is that you do not have an application ini file in the directory `/var/www/html/application/configs`. You will need to be aware where you have located the project configuration files. Without more detailed information it's difficult to provide better assistance, although a good starting point is the relevant [Zend_Application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html) section in the Zend Programmer's Reference Guide.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've read the Zend_Application portion of the manual.  Since I didn't use Zend tool (zf command line) to create the project, would that be the root cause of all of this?